# bug with horizontal scrolling

Tags: bug, design

I don't know if this really qualifies as a bug, since the repoduction steps are a bit silly, but here it is:

- log on programmers (with chrome 25 in my case)
- reduce the browser window to get an horizontal scroll bar
- scroll on the right

--> you get a different background on the right part

[image]

Comment: Reproduced on an older version of Firefox at work. Will test on Chrome and Safari when I get off.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 25 (Win7)

Comment: I can see *where* it is coming from... interesting...